# How to shut up Internet Explorer's "Speed up browsing by disabling add-ons" message?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

How can I make Internet Explorer stop telling me

> Speed up browsing by disabling add-ons

every Nth time I open it? I tell it to not ask me again but it keeps on pestering me anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the advice [here](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000466.htm), you can try opening the Group Policy Editor, navigating to

*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer*

and then setting "Disable add-on performance notifications" to Enabled.